Error upgrading Dataproc Serverless version from 2.1 to 2.2
I have changed the version of a Dataproc Serverless from 2.1 to 2.2 and now when I run it I get the following error:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider not a subtype
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:593)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1244)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1273)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1309)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1393)
    at scala.collection.convert.JavaCollectionWrappers$JIteratorWrapper.hasNext(JavaCollectionWrappers.scala:46)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.filterImpl(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:225)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.filterImpl$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:222)
    at scala.collection.convert.JavaCollectionWrappers$JIterableWrapper.filterImpl(JavaCollectionWrappers.scala:83)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.filter(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:218)
    at scala.collection.StrictOptimizedIterableOps.filter$(StrictOptimizedIterableOps.scala:218)
    at scala.collection.convert.JavaCollectionWrappers$JIterableWrapper.filter(JavaCollectionWrappers.scala:83)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:629)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:697)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:172)
    at com.dia.repositories.BigQueryAllocationRepository.process(BigQueryRepository.java:90)
    at com.dia.services.LoyaltyAllocationLoader.load(Test.java:18)
    at com.dia.LoyaltyAllocationMain.main(TestMain.java:42)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:569)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:1032)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:91)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:1124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:1133)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

The code has not been changed, these are the dependencies that are used:
 <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>0.34.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

I have tried to update to the latest versions but I get the same error:
<dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.13</artifactId>
            <version>0.41.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>

Does anyone have any idea what might be going on?

Any solution to this issue? I am also facing same issue.

Ideally you should have BigQuery dependency scope as provided. Dataproc serverless image 2+ is providing gcs and bigquery connectors inbuilt which will take higher precedence over your pom.xml
I am working on upgrades which is under development but you can take this pom.xml as your reference

You are facing this issue because Spark BigQuery connector already included by default in the 2.2 runtime and adding it as a dependency into your application jar causes class path conflict at runtime.
To fix this issue you just need to remove Spark BigQuery connector from your application jar by removing dependency from pom.xml or marking it as provided.
If you want to update default Spark BigQuery connector version you can use dataproc.sparkBqConnector.version=0.41.0 property when submitting Datparoc Serverless Spark batch job.
